# Can you drag-and-drop a marker on google maps? (javascript api)

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a phonegap app for iPhone/Android, heavily using the google maps javascript api.

Part of the app involves the user being able to place a marker wherever they want on the map, and the coordinates of that position then being sent to the app to be used in other processes which are not presently relevant.

So that's my problem: I'm not sure whether it's possible to drag and drop a marker, and I couldn't find any references to other people doing it after a few google searches.

Anybody got any info on this?

thanks!

Comment: Certainly possible with version 2, so it should be with version 3. My version 2 example is at http://www.acleach.me.uk/gmaps/draggableobject.htm -- drag the marker from the control area to where you want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it works in your app, but by default you can make a marker draggable, set the [**draggable-option**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MarkerOptions) to true.